# Proper way to display PNG using libpng onto a graphics buffer

Tags: c, libpng

I am trying to load png image using LibPNG c library onto a graphics buffer like so

```
//m_pBuffer is the graphics buffer
//row_pointers is the data from png
//width is width of image
//height height of image
//y = 100
//x = 100
//ScreenWidth = 1024
//channel_num = 4  

int pDst = (y + height - 1) * ScreenWidth + x;
for (y = height - 1; y >= 0 ; y--)
{
    png_bytep row = row_pointers[y];
    u32 *pBuffer = m_pBuffer + pDst;
    for(x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      png_bytep px = &(row[x * channel_num]);
      *pBuffer++ = RGBA(px[3], px[2], px[1], px[0]);
    }
    pDst -= ScreenWidth;
}
```

but what I get is a slightly distorted image. 
[image: which looks like this]

Yet this is the original pic
[image: which looks like this]

How do I get rid of the slightly yellow background and white borders?

This is how row_pointers is populated

```
    png_bytep row_pointers[height];

   int row = 0;
   for (row = 0; row < height; row++)
      row_pointers[row] = NULL;

   for (row = 0; row < height; row++)
      row_pointers[row] = (png_byte*)png_malloc(png_ptr, png_get_rowbytes(png_ptr, info_ptr));

   int pass = 0;   
   int number_passes = 1;
   for (pass = 0; pass < number_passes; pass++)
   {
      for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
      {
          png_read_rows(png_ptr, NULL, &row_pointers[j], 1);
      }
   }
   png_read_end(png_ptr, info_ptr);
```

Comment: Looks kind of like the buffer is maybe interpreting the alpha values differently - I would try fixing the `A` value at `0`,`127` and`255` to see how the buffer interprets those values then check they match your PNG - so in concrete terms, try writing `RGBA(px[3], px[2], px[1], alpha);` where `alpha` is 0, or 127 or 255.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, tried that, unfortunately that didn't do the trick. Turns out RGBA should be ARGB, with px[0] as red, 1 as green, 2 as blue, but my alpha is not working whether I put 0, 127 or 255

Comment: Check alpha is not pre-multiplied. Transparent should be 0 0 0 0, half transparent full red 128, 0, 0, 128 in a pre-multiplication scheme.

Comment: What graphics buffer are you using? Hardware & software-wise.

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean its software-wise, doing it on a raspberry pi zero

Comment: @Fredrick How are you alpha-blending the image with the existing background?

Comment: @IanAbbott I am not alpha-blending yet, was trying to remove the distortion first, unless alpha-blending will resolve that?

Comment: It's as though your "x" counter is off by 1.  Try ` for(x = 0 LE width; x++)`  instead of `for(x = 0; x LT width; x++)`

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson, thanks for the suggestion but it didn't work, I even tried putting a number smaller than the width, I still get a distorted image. I wonder if the pixels data is corrupted while loading, am following the libpng example and getting no errors.

Comment: You're not showing the allocation of row_pointers[]; maybe the stride is off by one there.

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson ok I have edited the question to show how its allocated.

Comment: Use lodePNG (not mine, though I maintain a copy) https://github.com/MalcolmMcLean/babyxrc if worried about calling libPNG correctly.

Comment: I will give it a try

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson oko, tried it and funny enough got the same result

Comment: Can't see a problem with the code.  What about "x" and "y" which you use before the loop but then use as iterators?  Should be OK but who knows...